# Configure IntelliJ to run Groovy Cucumber Geb framework

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, cucumber-jvm, geb

I'm trying to configure Run/Debug configurations in **IntelliJ** (v2017.2.5) to run cucumber tests written in **Groovy** (v2.4) using **Geb** (v1.1.1) in a **Gradle** project. I need to use **InternetExplorerDriver** (v3.6)

I tried:
 - Installing **Cucumber for Groovy** plugin and did following in **Edit Configurations** for IntelliJ:

- Main Class: `cucumber.api.cli.Main`
- Glue: `C:\automation\Project\src\cucumber\resources\steps C:\automation\Project\src\cucumber\resources\env`
- Feature or folder path: `C:/automation/Project/src/cucumber/features`
- Program Arguments: `--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter --monochrome`

  I'm getting following error when I run/debug a feature file:

> geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script15077602688031015554790$_run_closure2@55d58825'

I have tried looking for solutions for similar problem on stackoverflow which suggested upgrading selenium/groovy versions (i'm using latest version

- groovyVersion = '2.4'
- gebVersion = '1.1.1'
- seleniumVersion = '3.6.0'

I'm new to Groovy, Geb  and Gradle (I know Java and Maven) hence I suspect it could be a configuration issue.

FYI, the tests run fine through commandline. I need to get debugging in intellij working.

Comment: I noticed that at the time of initializing driver

[[ i.e.    driver = { new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities) } ]]

it is not able to find the System property "webdriver.ie.driver". [[    i.e. println(System.getProperty("webdriver.ie.driver") prints out 'null' on console.    ]]

This property is set in my build.gradle as a part of cucumber task.


Not sure how can I make sure that edit configuration in Intellij runs the gradle task that sets this property.

Comment: sorry missed your reply earlier @James Jones,
Thanks for the reply, 
yes, I had `webdriver.ie.driver` property set in my build.gradle as well... FYI, We can also provide it in VM Options of Intellij Edit Configurations like this:

`-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\automation\webdriver\iedriver\IEDriverServer.exe`

Comment: I don't recall making a comment to you. In any case you solved your problem yourself. Congrats and upvoted for good question.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the answer:

In my case the configuration in IntelliJ was wrong:

I used:
Main Class: `cucumber.api.cli.Main`

Glue: `C:\automation\Project\src\cucumber\resources\steps 
C:\automation\Project\src\cucumber\resources\env`

Feature or folder path: `C:/automation/Project/src/cucumber/features`

Program Arguments: `--plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.cucumber.java.run.CucumberJvmSMFormatter --monochrome`

module: `Project_cucumber`

Before launch: Build, Gradle task, Activate tool window:
`Run Gradle task 'Project: compileCucumberGroovy'`

Activate tool window [checked]

Comment: what about VM Options? Do you not need to add any?